# Match from current line until a line that doesn't match a pattern

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

I really tried searching but could not find anything (it's hard to know what exactly to search for).

I know how to do this with `sed`: print from current line until the line that matches SOMETHING:

```
sed -n '/1/,/SOMETHING/p'
```

But how do I do the same thing, but print from current line until the line that *does not* match SOMETHING?

e.g. pipe this into `sed`:

```
blah blah SOMETHING blah blah
blah blah SOMETHINGblahblahblah
SOMETHING blah blah
NO MATCH HERE
```

Then I want to filter out and print only the first 3 lines (but "3" can vary).

Answer (score 1):

This might not be as general as what you really want, but here’s a starting point:

```
 sed -n '/SOMETHING/!q;p'
```

This says: check for match to `/SOMETHING/`. 
If the line *doesn’t match* (using `!` to invert the result of the test), then quit. 
Otherwise, print this line and continue to the next line.

This is not immediately flexible enough to allow you to do what you asked for,
and also other manipulations on the file, all in the same `sed` command.

Comment: I partially retract and apologize for my flame.  We both overgeneralized.  My command, as you say, does _not_ work fine in ***all*** circumstances.  However, piping is not all you need to do to make it fail.  For example, `cat test.txt | (my command)`, `echo -e "blah…\nblah…" | …`, and `echo 'blah…(hit the <Enter> key)blah…'| …` all work.  (Please let me know if any of these fail when you try them.)  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Guess what doesn’t work?  `echo "Hello(<Enter>)world" ; sed -n '/SOMETHING/!q;p' test.txt`.  Also `ARBITRARY_VARIABLE="foo(<Enter>)bar" sed '1!q' test.txt`.  (See next comment.)  It turns out that, *if you have a literal newline (not a `\n` escape sequence) quoted **in double quotes** to the left of a command*, then strings in that command that look like history references (e.g., `!q`) are expanded (or, the shell _tries_ to expand them) even if they are quoted in single quotes.  I challenge anybody to explain this as anything other than a bug in `bash`.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  I offer you `sed '1!q'` for testing; it reads the first two lines of its input, prints them, and quits.  It is much shorter than the command in my answer, while having the same characteristics (it contains a string that looks like a history reference (i.e., `!q`) quoted in single quotes).

Answer (score 1):

You can try a loop in `sed`:

```
$ sed -n '{:loop p; n; /SOMETHING/b loop; q}' test.txt 
blah blah SOMETHING blah blah
blah blah SOMETHINGblahblahblah
SOMETHING blah blah
```

This:

- `:loop` creates a label named `loop`
- `p` prints the current line
- `n` fetches the next line
- `/SOMETHING/b loop` branches to `loop` if line matches `/SOMETHING/`
- `q` if the branch doesn't happen.

This prints one line in any case. (Probably can be fixed with G-Man's answer.)

Adapted from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20943542/2072269).